# How to I convert a string that contains a list of sets to list without changing the order of the sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string that contains a list of sets -

```
'[{13,18},{14,19}]'
```

I want it to be like this -

```
['[13,18]','[14,19]']
```

When I use ast.literal_eval() the order of the sets gets changed -

```
>>> 
>>> l1='[{13,18},{14,19}]'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> ast.literal_eval(l1)
[{18, 13}, {19, 14}]
>>>
```

Please suggest how can I keep the order of the elements inside the set. Thank you.

Comment: You want it to be a list of strings as per your proposed output? Or do you actually want a list of lists?

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered. You'll have to convert them to an ordered type (a list or a tuple) before parsing the string. Perhaps ultimately you'll need to abandon `ast` and write your own parser if your needs are  nontrivial.

Comment: sets are unordered, so you can not preserve the order of elements in a set, doesn't matter how you create a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set`s are inherently unordered ("arbitrarily ordered" is more precise), so the moment the `set` is parsed, the order is lost. If you can be sure none of the values contain a `{` or `}` that does not denote a `set`, and the desired end result is a `list` of `list`s (rather than the `list` of `set`s represented by your string) the solution is simple:

```
braces_to_brackets = str.maketrans('{}', '[]')  # Done once up front

mystr = '[{13,18},{14,19}]'
fixed_str = mystr.translate(braces_to_brackets)  # Replace curly braces with square brackets
parsed = ast.literal_eval(fixed_str)
```

which produces a `parsed` of `[[13, 18], [14, 19]]`, with the order preserved.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NCoMwEIX3OcVAF4kgQrCLdtFdbyESUh2pNCYhmZaKePY0Veimu3nM9378THdn6zRO3gUCHSndgu4wKnLqez2QIlwgUqgmnUXQNgq@rLwE3rS8ADjA1VkEZzuEp4chOEuMTXO2ZCNvFlmX8rSWizyW8ry2nA3jG3u1/zeu2mKNJhT/7QXzOkTsM5znVWYkDNoofGkjfklF8mG0JHa0SB8)

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of judicious replacements you could just do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

mystring = '[{13,18},{14,19}]'
mystring = mystring.replace('{', "'[").replace('}', "]'")
myval = literal_eval(mystring)
print(myval)
```

**Output:**

```
['[13,18]', '[14,19]']
```